# Using regular expression within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, stored-procedures

What is the regular expression pattern that enables every input besides characters? So far this is what i have -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Paging_Movies
@alphaChar char(1)
AS
if @alphaChar = '#'
select * from Movies where movies like '[0-9]%'
else
select * from Movies where movies like @alphaChar + '%'
```

Comment: Do you mean you want only numbers? Or all characters that aren't `a-z`?

Comment: this is for sql server 2008 r2, and yes all characters that aren't a-z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want true regular expression pattern matching you will need to roll your own CLR UDF.  This link goes over how to do that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Keep in mind that you can only do this in SQL Server 2005 or higher.

If you just want non-alpha you can do this:

```
'([^a-z])'
```

Here is the documentation for SQL Server `like`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2008 R2 has some [regular expression functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633712.aspx) built-in.

Here's a link explaining [how to extract them and use them in your own database](http://www.pettijohn.com/2010/08/regular-expressions-in-sql-2008-r2.html).

Comment: Very cool, didn't know about that.  So you are still creating a CLR function right?  Just from a Microsoft assembly instead of your own?

Comment: @Abe Miessler: I haven't used it personally, but yes - it just saves you rolling your own as there are already some in there!