# How to identify lowercase and special symbols in a string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using regular expression within a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365509/using-regular-expression-within-a-stored-procedure)

I need to validate a string, which should not contain contain lower case letters and Special Symbols. I have used below query, using this I'm able to find special symbols and unable to find lower case. Please suggest the best way.

```
DECLARE @InvNum VARCHAR(256);

SET  @InvNum='abcACB123'

IF (@InvNum LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9]%')
  BEGIN
    Print 'Enter valid Invoice #, Special characters and Lowercase Letters are not allowed'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    Print 'Validation Success'
  END
```

Comment: String validation is better done in your application layer as a rule.

Comment: Instead of trying to detect lower case letters you could simply convert the string to all upper case letters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HalfTrackMindMan almost had it right (and does for the sample data), but unfortunately, character ranges always expand out to include lowercase letters (so `bcABC123` would pass his validation):

```
DECLARE @InvNum VARCHAR(256);

SET  @InvNum='abcACB123'

IF (@InvNum COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS LIKE '%[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0-9]%')
  BEGIN
    Print 'Enter valid Invoice #, Special characters and Lowecase Letters are not allowed'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    Print 'Validation Success'
  END
```

(`[A-Z]` expands out as `AbBcCdDeEf...zZ`)

Which collation to use is a matter of preference - either a binary collation, or one that is Case Sensitive (`_CS`) and Accent Sensitive (`_AS`) will be suitable.

Comment: +1, was just about to add the same thing :)

Comment: Thanks for the script,@HalfTrackMindMan's script passes validaiton for the string bcABC123.Will it effects my query performance.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF (@InvNum COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9]%')
```

Comment: I personally would use `Latin1_General_Bin` but I think this is the way to go.

Comment: It works for me ,thanks @HalfTrackMindMan please suggest if it effects my query performance.