# Remove Spaces in SQL Server table data

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

We have the following data in table1.column1

```
A V John 
B V S Shultz
S Hanks
K L C Gove, P S Murphy
```

We need to remove space between one letter words. The data after conversion should like

```
AV John
BVS Shultz
S Hanks
KLC Gove, PS Murphy
```

Is it possible to write sql query regex to clean up the whole column data once. Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: To get regex functionality in SQL Server, at least as of 2008 R2, you have to use SQLCLR. Sadly.

Comment: @Jon there is a link for you :) http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/27/SQL-2005-Regular-Expression-Replace.aspx

Comment: @Jon this fact continues to be true in Denali - no native RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Using regular expression within a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365509/using-regular-expression-within-a-stored-procedure)

Is describes how to use regex in a SQL Server client.

You could also write a function using REPLACE

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with T-SQL but no one would call it beautiful ...

```
with cNames as (
select id=cast(id as tinyint), name=cast(name as varchar(50))
from   (values (1, 'A V John'), (2, 'B V S Shultz'), 
       (3, 'S Hanks'), (4, 'K L C Gove, P S Murphy')
       ) n (id, name)
),
cNumbers as (
select n=row_number() over (order by (select 1))
from (values (1),(1),(1),(1)) a (n)
cross join (values (1),(1),(1),(1)) b (n)
cross join (values (1),(1),(1),(1)) c (n)
),
cNameparts as (
select  c.id, n.n, c.name, 
        namepart=substring(c.name,n.n,charindex(' ',c.name+' ',n.n)-n.n)
from    cNames c
inner join cNumbers n
    on  substring(' '+c.name,n.n,1) = ' '
    and n.n < len(c.name)
)
select  name=
        (select case when len(namepart)>1 then ' ' else '' end +
                namepart +
                case when right(namepart,1)=',' then ' ' else '' end
        from    cNameparts np
        where   np.id = c.id
        for xml path(''))
from    cNames c
order by c.id;
```

Comment: Hello Mr. Manfred, Thanks for the code. I tried it, it's mostly working, failing for cases like "Rao C S R", "Lawrence D Souza". In first case it's changing to "RaoCS R" and in 2nd case to "LawrenceD Souza". It should be "Rao CSR" and "Lawrence D Souza". Your code has lots of logic, not sure where to change :) Please help.

Comment: I think, the code is working for cases where the one letter words are in the front, but failing if they are in the middle or at the right end. Thank you.

Comment: The examples had only letters in front, so I only tested this case. The logic is around the concatenating within the last subselect. You could add or omit spaces in other cases e.g. when np.n=1 ("first word") or when np.n+len(namepart)>len(c.name) ("last word").

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to a similar problem I had and this seem like it solved my issue where I had

```
Tom              Smith
Tom                   Smith
Tom                       Smith
replace(replace(replace(NAME,' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')
```

will all be Tom Smith based on [this](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg101106-story02.html) link

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regex you need to match the space between 2 adjacent single letters, then you'd replace that with `""` (a blank):

```
"(?<(^| )[a-zA-Z]) (?=[a-zA-Z]( |$))"
```

Note that this pattern doesn't include either of the letters - it's just the space between.

Comment: Using the above regex check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150977/perform-regex-replace-in-an-sql-query

Comment: Hi Bohemian, Thanks for the help. May I know how to use the above to replace the space between 2 adjacent single letters. Thanks.